# What would the ruby equivalent be to this python script?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```html
print ("{0:5s} {1:7s} {2:9s} {3:6s} {4:25s} {5:s}".format('Rank', 'Points', 'Comments', 'Hours', 'Sub', 'Link'))
    for ent in results: 
        print ("{0:5s} {1:7s} {2:9s} {3:6s} {4:25s} {5:s}".format(str(ent[0]), str(ent[1]), str(ent[2]), str(round(ent[3], 2)), str(ent[4]), str(ent[5])))
```

It is just printing outputs from an array but into rows. How can I mirror this in ruby?

Comment: I am getting a lot of downvotes on this so maybe I asked the question wrong but I was looking for a way to essentially print in columns with ruby.

Comment: It's been down-voted because of two primary reasons (*I can think of*): a) A lack of demonstrated attempt b) Unwillingness for the Python Community to help translate Python to Ruby and vica versa.

Comment: See: [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think this question would be OK If you showed some sample input data and the resulting output: Then someone who knows Ruby could help you without them also having to know Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python:

```
print ("{0:5s} {1:7s} {2:9s} {3:6s} {4:25s} {5:s}".format('Rank', 'Points', 'Comments', 'Hours', 'Sub', 'Link'))
```

Ruby:

```
puts "%-5s %-7s %-9s %-6s %-25s %-5s" % ['Rank', 'Points', 'Comments', 'Hours', 'Sub', 'Link']
```

Alternatively:

```
puts sprintf("%-5s %-7s %-9s %-6s %-25s %-5s", *['Rank', 'Points', 'Comments', 'Hours', 'Sub', 'Link'])
```

Comment: This helps me so much! I am still learning so this comparison really helps